# SQL Update command which performs a calculation in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to calculate the interest rate on outstanding invoices in my database.

I am working with Microsoft access database but asp.net/C# does not like my update statement.

asp.net/C# is telling me that there is a "Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression".

```
  "UPDATE s_transaction_enquiry 
   SET s_transaction_enquiry.interest_amount = DateDiff('d', s_transaction_enquiry.due_date, Now()) * (s_transaction_enquiry.payment_amount / 100 * sales_ledger.interest_rate) 
   FROM s_transaction_enquiry JOIN sales_ledger 
   ON s_transaction_enquiry.account_number=sales_ledger.account_number 
   WHERE s_transaction_enquiry.status = 'OPEN';
```

Can anyone help correct this statement?? I think the problem might be with this line:

```
// Im trying to calculate the number of days between today's date and the date in the database.

DateDiff('d', s_transaction_enquiry.due_date, Now())
```

Comment: Use proper JOIN syntax `UPDATE a SET.. FROM a JOIN b ON a.x=b.y ..`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to update two tables with one statement. @Mihai is correct.

Comment: I don't know about MS Access, but joining tables in an UPDATE is valid SQL Server syntax.

If you think it's the DateDiff try removing it and just putting in a hard-coded value as a test. If that doesn't fix the problem then remove the next thing you think it might be. Keep doing that until it works. Then you know what the problem is and you can focus on finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE s_transaction_enquiry 
INNER JOIN sales_ledger ON s_transaction_enquiry.account_number = sales_ledger.account_number 
SET s_transaction_enquiry.interest_amount = (DateDiff("d",[s_transaction_enquiry]![due_date],Now())*([s_transaction_enquiry]![payment_amount]/100*[sales_ledger]![interest_rate]))
WHERE (([s_transaction_enquiry]![status]='Open'));
```

This runs without errors in Access.

Answer (score 0):

i thought in MS Access, the SET part comes after the JOIN, when multiple tables are involved.

Try doing this

```
"UPDATE s_transaction_enquiry 
JOIN sales_ledger 
ON s_transaction_enquiry.account_number=sales_ledger.account_number 
SET s_transaction_enquiry.interest_amount = DateDiff('d', s_transaction_enquiry.due_date, Now()) * (s_transaction_enquiry.payment_amount / 100 * sales_ledger.interest_rate) 
WHERE s_transaction_enquiry.status = 'OPEN';"
```